# edit grub option programmatically

Tags: linux, operating-system, grub

I want to programmatically select the next os that will be run after the current os restart.
For example I've these os:

```
-Linux Mint
-Windows 7
```

i'm in linux now, and i want run windows after the restart. What file I have to modify?

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit `/etc/default/grub` and modify GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to the value you want (0 is the first entry in the list ). Save it then launch `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and set the variable `GRUB_DEFAULT` with `sed`.
Then regenerate grub's configuration with `update-grub`:

```
sed -i 's/GRUB_DEFAULT=[0-9]*/GRUB_DEFAULT=5/g' /etc/default/grub
update-grub
```

The number to place is the corresponding number of the boot menu entry. The first menu entry is number `0`.